# PHP on FastCGI (via Plesk) gives 404 for everything that doesn't end with .php

Tags: php, apache, nginx, fastcgi, plesk

I just switched my PHP to run from Apache to FastCGI (via Plesk). Now every file I try to access on my domain that's not a php file (like css, images, html ...) gives a 404.

Any idea of what it could be?

vhost specific config file (`/etc/nginx/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/mysite.com.conf`):

```
#ATTENTION!
#
#DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BECAUSE IT WAS GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY,
#SO ALL YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST THE NEXT TIME THE FILE IS GENERATED.

server {
    listen 99.99.99.99:443 ssl;

    server_name mysite.com;
    server_name www.mysite.com;
    server_name ipv4.mysite.com;

    ssl_certificate             /usr/local/psa/var/certificates/certEbk3rnT;
    ssl_certificate_key         /usr/local/psa/var/certificates/certEbk3rnT;
    ssl_session_timeout         5m;

    ssl_protocols               SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers                 HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    client_max_body_size 128m;

    root "/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs";
    access_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/mysite.com/logs/proxy_access_ssl_log";
    error_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/mysite.com/logs/proxy_error_log";

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://99.99.99.99:7081;
        proxy_set_header Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Accel-Internal /internal-nginx-static-location;
        access_log off;
    }

    location /internal-nginx-static-location/ {
        alias /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/;
        add_header X-Powered-By PleskLin;
        internal;
    }

}

server {
    listen 50.23.99.2:80;

    server_name mysite.com;
    server_name www.mysite.com;
    server_name ipv4.mysite.com;

    client_max_body_size 128m;

    root "/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs";
    access_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/mysite.com/logs/proxy_access_log";
    error_log "/var/www/vhosts/system/mysite.com/logs/proxy_error_log";

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://99.99.99.99:7080;
        proxy_set_header Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Accel-Internal /internal-nginx-static-location;
        access_log off;
    }

    location /internal-nginx-static-location/ {
        alias /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/;
        add_header X-Powered-By PleskLin;
        internal;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Requests of *.php files working because nginx transparent proxing it to apache, which catched by proper apache's vhost.

Statics files get 404 because:

1. proper nginx's vhost can't be found by nginx and request cathced by default vhost
   or
2. there some another nginx vhost which catch all requests(wildcard subdomain *.mysite.com for example).

No any useful advices here, just revise all your nginx configs.

Comment: I was actually having issues with Apache vs nginx. Nginx was serving the static files and apache the php ones. I had an error on ngingx config indeed and after stopping it, everything worked. Thanks